# Does g.711 == PCM

Tags: flash, audio-streaming

Please forgive me if this sounds ignorant, but I'm getting confused with regards to g.711 and PCM mulaw. Are they the same thing? The reason that I ask is in reference to Adobes' interchanging of PCM and g.711 in their docs; like this one for instance:
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/features._sl_id-contentfilter_sl_featuredisplaytypes_sl_new.html

For Adobe's part in this, the codec selection on the Microphone class only allows PCMU, PCMA, NellyMoser, or Speex; but they say they support g.711, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711):

> G.711 is an ITU-T standard for audio companding. It is primarily used
>   in telephony. The standard was released for usage in 1972. **Its
>   formal name is Pulse code modulation (PCM)** of voice frequencies. It
>   is required standard in many technologies, for example in H.320 and
>   H.323 specifications. It can also be used for fax communication over
>   IP networks (as defined in T.38 specification). G.711, also known as
>   Pulse Code Modulation (PCM), is a very commonly used waveform codec.
>   G.711 uses a sampling rate of 8,000 samples per second, with the
>   tolerance on that rate 50 parts per million (ppm). Non-uniform
>   (logarithmic) quantization with 8 bits is used to represent each
>   sample, resulting in a 64 kbit/s bit rate. There are two slightly
>   different versions; μ-law, which is used primarily in North America,
>   and A-law, which is in use in most other countries outside North
>   America.

Comment: Thanks for the lightning response! :)

Comment: Reading several years later but this is actually misleading... "of voice frequencies" should be bold too as G.711 is 'a' PCM having a filter on voice frequencies with 8 bit samples at 8KHz (64Kb/s stream)

Comment: not to mention that the question was in regards to μ-law specifically. i believe the last sentence is particularly important as well. reading only the bold here one might assume the answer to the op was "yes, they are the same." pcm == linear G.711. pcmu (aka PCM mulaw) is encoded, as is pcma.